# Disadvantage to storing medium-large amounts of data with APC?

Tags: php, apc

On my site, people frequently try to circumvent bans with tor/other proxies and from a list on blutmagie.de I've managed to disable people from registering with tor servers for the most part.  There is a tool for irc servers called blitzed open proxy monitor which basically checks all incoming connections on multiple dnsbl and bans them accordingly.  are there any services that do this for webservers?

about the question in the title: if i load this list of tor IPs(~4000) with APC, will it cause performance problems?  i've never used APC before so I don't know what amount of data it can handle exactly.

Comment: the majority of users in my community are skids and "getting around IP bans" means using tor browser.

Comment: Have you considered valid users running Tor? I am myself a Tor exit node which means my IP is also a Tor proxy.